# Subscriber callback function

Tags: ros, gazebo, c++, p3at

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I have made a subscriber to pioneer/laser/scan for the scan values of laser on P3AT.

When I run the subscriber, it just doesn't stop. It keeps on running. I want only a single value of the scan i.e. the ranges[] array.

And also the value of any index in ranges[] array fluctuates ranges[i] - .2  to ranges[i] + .2

How to get only a single array ranges[] when subscribing to the scan?

P.S. I am using these lines of code and obstaclesCallBack is my function for printing the scan values.

```
ros::NodeHandle laser_n;
ros::Subscriber sub = laser_n.subscribe<sensor_msgs::LaserScan>("pioneer/laser/scan", 1000, obstaclesCallback);
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/229916/subscriber-callback-function/) by [Arpit](https://answers.ros.org/users/23890/arpit/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2016-03-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

> When I run the subscriber, it just doesn't stop. It keeps on running.

That is the normal (and desired) behaviour of subscribers, yes.

> I want only a single value of the scan i.e. the ranges[] array.

Easiest is probably to use [ros::topic::waitForMessage(..)](http://docs.ros.org/indigo/api/roscpp/html/namespaceros_1_1topic.html#a9dfc4d8301e282af70ab81a7202d5ce5) for that.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-03-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1